# How to find Cells/IndexPaths that are adjacent horizantly and verticaly to specific Cell in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm wondering how to find the horizontally and vertically adjacent or surrounding cells/IndexPaths to a specific (red) cell in `UICollectionView`.

The red cell may be at any position.

I can find the red cell's `indexPath`, wether it is at any position.

I am attaching this Image file to clear my question more.
[image]

Any help or idea will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to take modulo of maximum number of cells in a single row.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy : let suppose max number of cells in a row is 4, then ?

Comment: Give me time for calculation. ok.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy : Yes Please

Comment: is number of columns are fixed?

Comment: @Indrajeet : No they can be change to any number from 2 to N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK If they are all the same size say 100x100 then get the cell you selected and

Ask the collectionView for the CGRect of the cell

Find the center.

Then ask the collectionView for cells at points, x - 100, x + 100, y - 100, y + 100.

Then see which are not nil?

Comment: This short trick works to get all these `indexPaths`.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm

**Assuming :**

There are four cells in each row.

**Calculation :**

1. `int rowCount = 4` // Total no of cells in a row. As you already described it.
2. `int lastRow = totalCell / rowCount` // last row number.
3. `int colNo = index % rowCount` // column Number i.e. this index is at which column
4. `int rowNo = index / rowCount` // this index is at which row

**Algo**

```
1. if `colNo == 0` // cell is the left most.
     if `rowNo == 0` // index of first row
        adjacent = index + 1, index + rowCount
     else if `rowNo == lastRow` // index of last row
        adjacent = index + 1, index - rowCount
     else 
        adjacent = index + 1, index - rowCount

2. if `colNo == 1` // cell is the second in its row .
     if `rowNo == 0` // index is at first row
        adjacent = index - 1, index + 1, index + rowCount
     else if `rowNo == lastRow` // index is at last row
        adjacent = index - 1 ,index + 1, index - rowCount
     else 
        adjacent = index + 1, index - rowCount, index - 1

3. if `colNo == 2` // cell is the third in row.
     if `rowNo == 0` // index of first row
        adjacent = index - 1, index + 1, index + rowCount
     else if `rowNo == lastRow` // index of last row
        adjacent = index - 1, index + 1, index - rowCount
     else 
        adjacent = index + 1, index - rowCount, index - 1

4. if `colNo == 3` // cell is the left most.
     if `rowNo == 0` // index of first row
        adjacent = index - 1, index + rowCount
     else if `rowNo == lastRow` // index of last row
        adjacent = index - 1, index - rowCount
     else 
        adjacent = index - 1, index - rowCount
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution does not take any spacing or different cell sizes into account but to give you an idea of how it could work:

```
private func selectCellAndAdjacentCellsAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        var cellsToSelect: [UICollectionViewCell] = [cell]

        // get adjacent cells

        // top
        if let topIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: cell.center.x, y: cell.center.y - cell.frame.height)), let topCell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: topIndexPath) {
            cellsToSelect.append(topCell)
        }
        // left
        if let leftIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: cell.center.x - cell.frame.width, y: cell.center.y)), let leftCell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: leftIndexPath) {
            cellsToSelect.append(leftCell)
        }
        // bottom
        if let bottomIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: cell.center.x, y: cell.center.y + cell.frame.height)), let bottomCell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: bottomIndexPath) {
            cellsToSelect.append(bottomCell)
        }
        // right
        if let rightIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x: cell.center.x + cell.frame.width, y: cell.center.y)), let rightCell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: rightIndexPath) {
            cellsToSelect.append(rightCell)
        }

        // select cells
        for cellToSelect in cellsToSelect {
            cellToSelect.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I will try and back to you :)